# How to return only the occurrence of a specific name in R

Tags: r, regex, filtering

```
df=read.delim("names.csv")
> df
        name
1     LIDSAY
2    STEFANY
3   FEDERICO
4   LEONARDO
5    DOROTHY
6       RUTH
7        AMR
8    Mohamed
9   FLORENCE
10     MANAL
11   MILDRED
12    FARIDA
13   LILLIAN
14    SYLVIA
15 ELIZABETH
16   FRANCES
17    EVELYN
18     MARIE
19   SHIRLEY
20       AMR
```

When I ask the following to return the name farida from the list it only writes integer(0)

```
t=grep ("FARIDA", names(df))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution using `which`

```
which(df$name=="FARIDA")

  [1] 12
```

Comment: Please test your code before posting. I can spot three errors in what you wrote here. I'd also argue that your second answer is short and perfect, I wish you just deleted that first answer which is rather awful.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're calling `names` for some reason which returns:

```
names(df)

> names(df)
[1] "name"
```

**Try this instead:**

```
grep ("FARIDA", df$name)
```

PS:  maybe you'd find `%in%` of use instead as it gives a logical TRUE/FALSE and is faster than `grep`.  Wrap it with `which` if you need a specific index or use the logical vector instead as seen below:

```
df$name %in% "FARIDA"

## With indexing
df[df$name %in% "FARIDA", ]
```

Comment: +1 - but as the OP is looking for a single name `==` makes more sense than `%in%`.